# How can I modify the first object in a React UseState array?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[SANDBOX LINK](https://codesandbox.io/embed/lucid-einstein-ovodj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I am using a `FormControl` to try to update my state which defaults at `const [numberOfChildren, updateNumberOfChildren] = useState([{age: undefined}]);` I want to modify the first object in the array when a user clicks a button, and then enters a value in an input. I try to update the `age` with another `useState` Currently, the array's first object is `{age: undefined}` and is not updated by the `useState` hook

The code looks like this

```
 <FormControl
 placeholder="Age"
 aria-label="Age"
 aria-describedby="basic-addon2"
 onChange={async (e) => {
       await updateAge(e.target.value);
 }}
 />
```

updated by the button

```
<Button
  className="align-button"
  onClick={async (e) => {
         e.preventDefault();
         if(numberOfChildren.length < 1) {
                   await updateNumberOfChildren((children) => [
                         ...children
                   ]);
                   } else {
                      await updateNumberOfChildren((children) => [
                       ...children,
                         { childAge: age },
                       ]);
                       }

                        console.log(numberOfChildren)
                            }}
                            style={{ width: "100%" }}
                            variant="outline-primary"
                            type="submit"
                            size="lg"
                        >
                            Add Child
                        </Button>{" "}
```

Here is a sandbox, please have a look at the console for the output [SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/embed/lucid-einstein-ovodj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you were doing it using `const [age, updateAge] = useState(undefined);` won't get you what you want because by doing that you'll only update the latest added child so you can't go back to the first one and modify or even modify any previous children after adding them as the current setup has no way to differentiate between which one you're trying to modify.

So, The idea here is that you need to identify each object in the array with something unique so I changed the object structure to the following:

```
const [numberOfChildren, updateNumberOfChildren] = useState([
        { id: 1, age: undefined }
      ]);
```

And here's how you update the state explaining every line:

```
// Update numberOfChildren state
  function updateData(e) {
    // Grab the id of the input element and the typed value
    const { id, value } = e.target;
    // Find the item in the array that has the same id
    // Convert the grabed id from string to Number
    const itemIndex = numberOfChildren.findIndex(
      item => item.id === Number(id) 
    );

    // If the itemIndex is -1 that means it doesn't exist in the array
    if (itemIndex !== -1) {
      // Make a copy of the state
      const children = [...numberOfChildren];
      // The child item
      const child = children[itemIndex];
      // Update the child's age
      children.splice(itemIndex, 1, { ...child, age: value });
      // Update the state
      updateNumberOfChildren(children);
    }
  }
```

And when you add a new child the latest added child will have the id of the `numberOfChildren` state length plus 1 as I used 1 as a starting point:

```
onClick={e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  updateNumberOfChildren([
    ...numberOfChildren,
    { id: numberOfChildren.length + 1, age: undefined }
  ]);
}}
```

Finally, If you want to check any state value don't use `console.log()` after `setState()` because `setState()` is `async` so you won't get the changes immediately and since you're using hooks the only way around this is `useEffect()`:

```
// Check the values of numberOfChildren whenever they get updated
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("numberOfChildren", numberOfChildren);
  }, [numberOfChildren]);
```

Here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-napier-r1vpu?file=/src/App.js). Hopefully everything now is crystal clear.